# How can I find documents whose child documents contain fields totalling a value?

Tags: elasticsearch

A book series has many books. A book has a number of pages.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "series": {
      "properties": {
        "name": { "type": "string" },
        "books": {
          "type": "nested", 
          "properties": {
            "title": { "type": "string"  },
            "page_count": { "type": "integer"  }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I index some book series.

```
{
  "name": "Harry Potter",
  "books": [
    {
      "title": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",
      "page_count": 100
    },
    {
      "title": "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets",
      "page_count": 100
    }
  ]
}

{
  "name": "The Long Earth",
  "books": [
    {
      "title": "The Long Earth",
      "page_count": 150
    },
    {
      "title": "The Long Mars",
      "page_count": 150
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to find all book series where the total number of pages of the books in that series is greater than or equal to 250. This query should return the `"The Long Earth"` series, which has 300 total pages, but not the `"Harry Potter"` series, which only has 200 total pages.

How can I structure such a query?

As far as I can tell, nested queries only allow you to look into individual nested docs (e.g. find a series that has at least one book with more than 120 pages). I've never worked with scoring before (only used binary queries), and I'm starting to think maybe that holds the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [nested aggregations](https://blog.knoldus.com/2016/01/19/working-with-nested-aggregation-of-elasticsearch/). You'll want to apply nested sum aggregation and filter on that.